# INSERT INTO table from form with checkboxes

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to insert multiple entries into a table using a single form.

Desired outcome:

```
DESTINATION_TABLE
DATE       | PLACE | THEME | PARTICIPANT
dd.mm.yyyy   A       X       1
dd.mm.yyyy   A       X       2
dd.mm.yyyy   B       Y       3
```

PLACE and PARTICIPANT are to be selected from values contained in other tables, while DATE and THEME are entered using text boxes. Only one value is to be inserted into the table at a time for DATE, PLACE and THEME, but I would like to be able to insert multiple PARTICIPANT, with a new row for each PARTICIPANT selected.

Adding new entries for DATE, PLACE and THEME via a form works (using *CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO...*).

How can I create a form that would let me select PARTICIPANT from a subform (ideally with checkboxes) filtered from the value in PLACE, and add an entry in DESTINATION_TABLE *for each* PARTICIPANT selected ?

Comment: This is quite a broad question; can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm sorry, but I don't know how to slice this problem into sub-problems. Do you have any suggetions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way of doing it, with your current setup is to:

1. add a `Yes/No` field to your participants table, default to `No`. We'll call this field `Selected`
2. Bind your subform to the participants table, the user will be able to check each participant from this view(using the `Selected` field).
3. From which ever event you're using to save you data(e.g. Button Click), create a recordset(`rs`) based on the selected  participants from the participants table(`SELECT * FROM PARTICIPANT WHERE Selected = True`. Loop through each record in the recordset(`rs`) and execute your code `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO...)`, taking the value of the participant(`rs("Participant")`) from the recordset.
4. Once the loop is finished, update the participants table setting the `Selected` field to `No`. `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE PARTICIPANT SET Selected = False WHERE Selected = True"`
5. Refresh/Requery your sub form data if needed

Substitute above object names with yours.

Comment: Thanks @jbud, I'll try it as soon as possible. Creating this loop will be a good lerarning opportunity for me!

Comment: Quick update: steps 1) and 2) from your solution worked perfectly, I was able to get the form I wanted. However, I got lost researching the recordsets (I am in no way familiar with VBA), so I used another, less elegant method: I created an empty temp table that I populated using DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tmpTable RIGHT JOIN Participant ... WHERE Participant.Checkbox = True", and then "INSERT INTO Tabl SELECT [...] FROM tmpTable". I am very aware that it's a truly horrendous solution, but it does the trick... Thanks again @jbud for pointing mein the right direction!